# TypeScript: Global static variable best practice

Tags: typescript

I have this class where I need to increment a number each time the class is instantiated.
I have found two ways to this where both ways works, but I am not sure yet on what is the best practice

1. declare the variable in the module scope

   ```
   module M {
     var count : number = 0;
     export class C {
       constructor() {
         count++;
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. declare the variable in the class scope and access it on Class

   ```
   module M {
     export class C {
       static count : number = 0;
       constructor() {
         C.count++;  
       }
     }
   }
   ```

My take is example two as it does not adds the count variable in the module scope.

See also: [C# incrementing static variables upon instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132413/c-sharp-incrementing-static-variables-upon-instantiation)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Definitely method 2 since that is the class that is using the variable. So it should contain it.

In case 1 you are using a variable that will become confusing once you have more than one classes in there e.g:

```
module M {

  var count : number = 0;

  export class C {
    constructor() {
      count++;
    }
  }

  export class A{
  }
}
```

Comment: If class C isn't the only one using the count I wouldn't be bothered seeing it at the package level.  What's more important is the variable name.  In most places in the code the name 'count' isn't enough information about what it represents.  I'd prefer 'numConstructed' or 'constructedCount'.

Comment: agree, they should be specific! The code used here was just examples

Answer (score 3):

Both of them are okay, but `method 2` more self explanatory, which means its less confusing when your code get more complex unless you are using the `count` to increase each time you instantiate a class from that module then `method 1` is the way to go.

I prefer to do it this way:

```
module M {
  export class C {
    static count : number = 0;
    constructor() {
      C.count++;  
    }
  }
}
```