# Ionic2/Angular 2 Observable.timer duplicate

Tags: angular, timer, duplicates, ionic2, observable

I created a Observable.timer in my Ionic 2 project to countdown the time (e.g. 00:00:59->00:00:00). For example, I created the timer in a page called "PageB" and below is the typescript code:

```
export class PageB {
 constructor(){
this.timer = Observable.timer(500,500).map(i=>this.result-i*503).take((this.result-575999970)/503).subscribe(i => 
{
this.time=i;
console.log(i);
console.log(moment(this.time).format('HH:mm:ss'));
});
}
}
```

Console.log output for the above code:

### [image: Console.log output for the above code:]

However, I got a problem that this timer will be duplicated when I leave from PageB to previous page and then go back to PageB again (PageB->previous page->PageB).

The duplicated situation:

[image]

---

You can see that 00:00:47, 00:00:46 and the rest are duplicated so many times. I cannot use `"this.timer.unsubscribe()"` to stop the timer when leaving PageB because I need it keep counting down in the background.

Therefore, could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: it kinda looks like the duplication that happens when watching for network connection where events fire twice... the suggestion for that problem was to make a service where it filters the fired events...http://stackoverflow.com/a/42454236/7266219 
not sure if this gonna help.. but have a look.

Comment: it seems not suitable in my problem.... thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

You could move the Observable to a provider and use [Subject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) to ensure there is only one timer.

```
export class TimerProvider {
 constructor(){
}
timerSubject:Subject<any>;

loadTimer(){

Observable.timer(500,500).map(i=>this.result-i*503).take((this.result-575999970)/503).subscribe(i => 
{
this.timerSubject.next(i);
});
}

getTimer(){
 if(!this.timerSubject(){
   this.timerSubject = new Rx.Subject();
   this.loadTimer();
 }
 return timerSubject.asObservable();
}
}
```

In your pageB:

```
export class PageB {
 constructor(private timeProvider:TimerProvider){
this.timer = this.timeProvider.getTime().subscribe(i => 
{
this.time=i;
});
}
}

ngOnDestroy(){
   this.timer.unsubscribe();
}
```

You will have a single timer as long as your provider is singleton and it will start the first time page B is opened.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried the null check but still not work......

Comment: since it is set in the constructor.. your page is created multiple times.. maybe set `timer` as static? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462839/typescript-global-static-variable-best-practice

Comment: it works when using a null check and set timer as static. However, it has another problem that I cannot get the value of "this.time" variable again when I leave PageB and go back, which means I can only get the value of "this.time" when I go PageB at the 1 first time.

Comment: so even time needs to be static in that case.. not sure if it fits your use case though.. or maybe move the timer to a singleton provider/app.component?

Comment: If I cannot get the "this.time" again, I cannot show the countdown number on the UI of PageB again if I leave PageB and go back....

Comment: to show the global variable e.g "this.time" to the front-end html in ionic is using {{time}}. So do you know how to show the static variable in this case? thanks

Comment: @TommyMok try my updated logic.. static would not be such a good idea

Comment: thanks for the updated logic. However, what should I import in my ts to get "new Rx.Subject();" work? It erros me "cannot find the name Rx" thanks

Comment: i tried the updated logic, it works for me. However, when I update the `this.result` in `Observable.timer(500,500).map(i=>this.result-i*503).take((this.result-575999970)/503).subscribe(i =>` It will have two countdown timers e.g. for the 1st timer, this.result=10, so the timer is 10..9..8; if I updated this result=11, then the timer is 11..10. However, the 1st timer is still here. So how can I stop the 1st timer and use the 2nd updated timer only? thanks

Comment: Or is it possible to have another method to make the timer in Ionic 2 project? thanks

Comment: you can save the timer subscription in the provider and unsubscribe when you want to update